Conditional Formatting formula to highlight all numbers after first missing number in a serial number list where one cell can contain multiple values
Google Sheet Link
Sheet Name: Conditional Formatting (Part 2):

(Rows which meets conditional formatting are highlighted RED)
Explanation:
For "STUDIO" A in "FIN YEAR" X-X first missing number is 7 so after 7 all number in A in X-X would be red, similarly for O-O first missing number is 3 so after 3 all numbers in A in O-O would be red.
For "STUDIO" B in "FIN YEAR" O-O first missing number is 1 so after 1 all number in B in O-O would be red.
QUESTION: I want a formula for conditional formatting which gives TRUE for all the numbers after the first missing number for each "STUDIO" in each "FIN YEAR". (As shown in above image)
NOTE:
Numbers start from 1 for each "FIN YEAR" for each "STUDIO".
Numbers can repeat any number of time.
Every input is random, there is no order for any columns.
One cell can have multiple values.
TABLE:



STUDIO
FIN YEAR
NUMBER
(OUTPUT) CONDITIONAL FORMATING




A
X-X
3,4



A
X-X
5,8
TRUE


A
X-X
1



A
O-O
8
TRUE


A
X-X
6



B
X-X
1



B
X-X
2



C
X-X
1



B
O-O
4
TRUE


B
X-X
3



A
X-X
2
TRUE


C
X-X
2



C
X-X
3



A
O-O
1



A
O-O
2



A
O-O
2



A
O-O
4
TRUE


C
O-O
1



C
O-O
1




Please do not mark this as duplicate question of PART 1, because I was asked to create a separate question for this PART 2.


Here's one approach you may test out:
The formula is applied at column_D & then conditional format applied to columns A,B,C since such computational-heavy formulas when used directly as a conditional formatting rule can extremely slow down the sheet.
=let(Ξ,map(let(z,sort(unique(A2:A&B2:B)),filter(z,z<>"")),lambda(Λ,hstack(Λ,let(x,split(join(",",filter(C:C,A:A&B:B=Λ)),","),y,sequence(1,max(x)),ifna(min(filter(y,isna(xmatch(y,x))))))))),
 map(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,lambda(a,b,c,if(counta({a,b,c})<>3,,let(Σ,index(xmatch(vlookup(a&b,filter(Ξ,index(Ξ,,2)<>""),2,),split(c,","),1)),if(isnumber(Σ),true,))))))



This works great, thanks! So would this "slow down" be applicable for this answer too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78309855/8866238 . Should I create a helper for this at Column D just like you did?

sure.. column D or any other column of your choice should suffice.

Thanks! It would be great if you could help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78460369/conditional-formatting-formula-to-highlight-repeated-strings-in-different-cells

conditional formatting can highlight the whole cell & not selective strings(within the cell) which are repeating. I mean as per your screenshot there, only repeated string is red; rest are black in a single cell!

I mean the whole cell only, have marked it red for understanding purpose only. That is why I have added a output column. Sorry if I was not clear!

Have updated the question!
