Conditional Formatting formula to highlight repeated strings in different cells or inside the same cell
Google Sheet Link

(Not able to covert to makrdown stackoverflow table because of Char(10))
(Have marked repeated strings as red now just for understanding purpose)
QUESTION: I want a formula for conditional formatting (Column B) which gives TRUE for all the strings repeating either in the same cell itself or different cells. (As shown in above image)
NOTE:
There can be any number of strings in a cell.
Strings can repeat any number of times.
Every input is random, there is no order for any columns.
One cell can have multiple values.

You can use:
=AND(A2<>"",SUMPRODUCT(1<COUNTIF(SPLIT(A$2:A,CHAR(10)),SPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)))))



This is amazing, took me like 2hrs to understand. Thanks a ton!
